# Use enumitem in thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, enumitem

I'm trying to set the \labelindent length in the "thebibliography" environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

blblabla...

\begin{thebibliography}{300} 
\addtolength{\labelwidth}{0.2in}
\addtolength{\labelindent}{0.2in}

\bibitem[PP53]{PP59} Peter Pan, 1953.

\bibitem[SB59]{SB59} Sleeping Beauty, 1959.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The "thebibliography" environment is a list, and the option with \labelwidth works correctly, but the order for \labelindent is ignored. Any idea?

Comment: `thebibliography` env directly uses `\list` from latex2e kernel to construct the list structure, and `\labelindent` is only defined inside list envs (re)defined by `enumitem`. Therefore `\labelindent` is not defined inside `thebibliography`. You can achieve similar indent effects by using latex2e dimensions only, see https://latexref.xyz/list.html#list .

Comment: `\leftmargin` does not work either

Answer (score 1):

Please use the correct option values

[image: Option value should be the maximum value of the list]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}  % to show frames
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % for dummy text


\begin{document}
blblabla...

\begin{thebibliography}{[SB59]}
  \bibitem[PP53]{PP59} Peter Pan, 1953. \lipsum[2]
  \bibitem[SB59]{SB59} Sleeping Beauty, 1959.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `thebibliography` environment defined by standard classes contains `\@openbib@code`, which can be used as a hook.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}  % to show frames
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % for dummy text

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@openbib@code}
  {\addtolength{\leftmargin}{2em}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
blblabla...

\begin{thebibliography}{300}
  \bibitem[PP53]{PP59} Peter Pan, 1953. \lipsum[2]
  \bibitem[SB59]{SB59} Sleeping Beauty, 1959.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: add leftmargin inside "thebibliography" env]